# Letting users create their own models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, database-design

In my Rails project, I have the two similar models `SafetyTest` and `TeamDue`. Their fields are exactly the same, and they differ only in name. Each instance `belongs_to` a `Student`.

I would like to add the ability to create *new* models that follow the structure of the two above. So maybe I'd like to add `MedicalForm`. I don't want to do this over a CLI as a developer, but provide an interface in the view so that administrators can add their own.

Let's say that `SafetyTest`, `TeamDue`, and `MedicalForm` can all be described with the name `SeasonalRequirement`. What would be the best and most maintainable way to implement my idea?

I'm not experienced in Rails, but an idea that I had was to incorporate the models above into one comprehensive model called `SeasonalRequirement`, and just add a `type` column for every type. The problem with this: How would users create a new type of seasonal requirement (such as `MedicalForm`)? And how would I even determine what types of seasonal requirements there are when I'm trying to display a separate section for every one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not used RoR much, bu it seems like a bad idea to have the users change the structure of the database.

What might work is something like this:

```
additional_student_columns
--------------------------
id
name
```

and add another table:

```
additional_student_values
--------------------------
student_id
column_id
value (string)
```

The disadvantage of this is that it can use just string values

Comment: I'm not sure how this would work, and using two tables seems not very Rails-like to me. Lastly, I didn't propose that users would change the database; what I proposed would just create new fields. And if they did, I should clarify that these "users" would be admins who would only screw up their own site.

Comment: The column_id references additional_student_columns.id, admins can add a new column by adding a value there.

Comment: I might just go with your solution, since it's so simple.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a polymorphic or STI relationship for this.

See more details at: http://code.alexreisner.com/articles/single-table-inheritance-in-rails.html

I would use STI to model this.

Comment: I have the basics of STI down, but here's the problem: STI needs a subclass for every type— how is that supposed to work dynamically?

Comment: Hi, check this on how to create ruby classes dynamically, http://www.dzone.com/snippets/create-classes-runtime and look in to some ruby meta programming as well

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the help so far. However, I'm not so sure that this is the right solution for me. Just look at the workarounds required in [this article](http://www.christopherbloom.com/2012/02/01/notes-on-sti-in-rails-3-0/)! Maybe njr's solution is the simpler one.